# Android runtime exception on note5: libgles_MALI not found system.loadlibrary

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opencl, galaxy

Android jni project created on visual studio 2015 fail on runtime.
    `system.loadlibrary (mylib)` fails when invoking `dlopen (OpenCl..)`.
    Error message: `can not open libGLES_mali.so`.

IcCan see on my board next files:

```
\vendor
      lib
           libOpenCL.so --> libOpenCl.so.1
           libOpenCl.so.1 --> libOpenCl.so.2
           libOpenCL.so.2 --> vendor\lib\egl\libGLES_mali.so
           egl
                   libGLES_mali.so
```

For debug I have tried `system.loadlibrary` (OPENCL) which return with no errors.